# JackMagic7 website bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I was recently hired by a kid at my school to make a website for him. I'm new to bootstrap and I'm not very good, but I thought i was getting the hang of it when my navbar button(right, top when collapsed.) wouldn't work. Please help.

here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link type="text/css" href="jack.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-static-top" id="my-navbar">


<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header"></div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target="#navbar-collapse" >
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" id="orange" href="">JackMagic7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#magic">Magic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pics">Pics</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>

<script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put this in a jsfiddle, it would make it easier to see what is supposed to be happening

Comment: What do you mean by "navbar button wouldnt work?" Can you clarify please? If you describe the desired behavior - or what "broke" about it - it will make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the nav Tag, here is the correct code, I also fixed some small failures

I would recomend you an Editor/IDE, which supports syntax hihlighting, to prevent such Failures, another cool tool for debugging is the Extension "Firebug" for Firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link type="text/css" href="jack.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-static-top" id="my-navbar">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"></div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" target="#navbar-collapse" >
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" id="orange" href="">JackMagic7</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#magic">Magic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pics">Pics</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>

    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey I tried using this code, but It didn't work. Do you think it could be a problem with my browser/computer? What IDE should I use I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: I'm also using a post on YouTube from Nov. 2014 to learn bootstrap. Is that a wise decision?